# Overriding Menus in Swift with Storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, action, menuitem, first-responder

I am writing a Swift Application in xCode and have no problem creating a new menuitem and wiring it up so that the sent action responds to a function in my ViewController.  Where I  am having difficulty is if I try to override one of the existing Apple, preset menu actions.
For example, I would like to display my own help so I want to override the **showHelp:** function that is currently the action set for the help menu.

This what I did.  Remember, I am using a storyboard and this worked for new menu items.

1. Selected the Attributes inspector for the FirstResponder of the
   MainMenu.xib
2. Added a new action **showMyHelp:** and I left the type as id
3. Created a new function called **showMyHelp()** in my ViewController
4. Selected the **myApplicationName help** menuitem from the main menu and then from the **connections** panel, dragged from **Sent Actions** to the **first responder** of the **MainMenu** and selected **showMyHelp** from the selection list.  The Sent Actions now reads action > First Responder / showMyHelp:

However, when I run the app, the help menu is now disabled and I cannot access it.

Again, if i repeat this method for one of my custom menuItems that I have added, it works fine.  The menuItem is not disabled and the action is performed.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I discovered what my problem was.
In step 3 above, I needed to include the sender: AnyObject? as a parameter when calling the function so **showMyHelp(sender: AnyObject?)**

All is well now.  Next step is to figure out how to manage enabling and disabling menu items as required.

Comment: To future readers, I had to make it `someFunc(_ sender: AnyObject?)` to get the menu item to not be greyed out

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helpful post. However, i find a little thing to make it working:

- Function signature should start with `@IBAction`

```swift
@IBAction func showMyHelp(_ sender: AnyObject?)
```

- This function should be defined in your `AppDelegate`.

For the next, follow the previous steps and it works ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement on the ViewController.
But, First you indicate flag for accept to first responder.

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
  // ..
  override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
  }

  @IBAction func showHelp(_ sender: Any) {
    print("showHelp")
  }
```